# AEM Error with ExternalLoginModule

Tags: aem, author

I created author AEM6 on `localhost:4504`.

When I load any page on the server, I have a lot of the following errors:

```
org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.ExternalLoginModule No IDP found with name cortexCSR. Will not be used for login.

org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.ExternalLoginModule No IDP found with name cortex. Will not be used for login.

org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.ExternalLoginModule No IDP found with name ldap. Will not be used for login.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may have an instance that is configured for LDAP authentication.  Check these URLs to see if that is the case.

Go to http://localhost:4504/system/console/configMgr and search for "ExternalLoginModule" or "org.apache.jackrabbit.oak" and then edit the config to see what is set for any items you find.  It sounds like you have an ExternalLoginModuleFactory configured to look for an LDAPIdentityProvider that hasn't been configured.  Most likely you need to add the configuration for the providers.  See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/security/ldap-config.html for info on how to configure those.   It could be that there is an OSGI config file that is runmode specific, so if your localhost isn't running with the same runmode it would not have applied the configuration in that case.

Also see http://abani-behera.blogspot.com/2014/07/ldap-integration-with-aem6-osgi-config.html for more details.