# Internal server error when trying to build and deploy to AEM

Tags: apache, maven, aem, crx

My local AEM instance suddenly stopped working when I switched branches in git and installed the package with
`mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage`.

The build failed with `[ERROR] Request to http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp failed, response=Internal Server Error`

My error log shows the following errors:

`25.10.2018 11:52:33.607 *ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1540504353564] POST /crx/packmgr/service.jsp HTTP/1.1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.ExternalLoginModule No IDP found with name 0654f74c177ec80b60f7922a9a6195cf. Will not be used for login.
25.10.2018 11:52:33.607 *ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1540504353564] POST /crx/packmgr/service.jsp HTTP/1.1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.ExternalLoginModule No IDP found with name a9dea3b044e912071cbffd4839016d2e. Will not be used for login.
25.10.2018 12:00:30.005 *INFO* [sling-default-2-Registered Service.1079] com.adobe.granite.taskmanagement.impl.jcr.TaskArchiveService archiving tasks at: 'Thu Oct 25 12:00:30 HST 2018'
25.10.2018 12:00:58.610 *ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1540504858546] POST /crx/packmgr/service.jsp HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
java.io.IOException: Unable to get component of class 'interface org.apache.sling.rewriter.Generator' with type 'htmlparser'.`

I've tried adding `<useProxy>false</useProxy>` to my parent POM file as suggested on a similar thread posted here but that also did not work. I've tried recloning the repo and starting over but since it's a server error that did nothing.

**Additional Info:**

Running on Windows 10

AEM 6.4

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: This error log could be related to LDAP or a custom login module. Perhaps the feature branch you switched to contained some configuration related to this feature? I'd start by checking if all OSGi bundles are active in the Felix console. If there's nothing obvious there, consider viewing a diff between your two branches and you might just find some clues.

Comment: Is there a workaround for http://localhost:4502/system/console/ ? My localhost is throwing a 500 internal error on login so I don't have access to the felix console there.

Comment: Something similar -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35465944/4173416

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue actually happened when I switched branches and installed and deployed the package over the existing package in AEM. By removing the quickstart folder and restarting the JAR file, thus creating a new AEM directory, I was able to install and deploy the correct branch without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. The issue actually happened when I switched branches and installed and deployed the package over the existing package in AEM. By removing the quickstart folder and restarting the JAR file, thus creating a new AEM directory, I was able to install and deploy the correct branch without error.